# How to customize Libreoffice user interface via extension development?

Tags: user-interface, plugins, libreoffice, basic

I'm learning how to develop Basic extensions for LibreOffice, but I not found documentation on UI customization.

I really would like to add some new funcionalities to LibreOffice.

How can I create new elements on LibreOffice interface? It's possible? Is there some tutorial?

Answer (score 2):

If you have created some macros that is possible to meet some others user needs then you should provide a menu or an icon to execute them. The most friendly way to do so is to use BasicAddonBuilder which is it self an extension aiming to provide a step procedure to package your macros into an extension. More info and installation files [here](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Extensions_Packager)

Some things to keep in mind:

If you have many different macros to offer then you may wish to provide an additional menu for your extension but be careful that this may be considered a disadvantage by many users except if your extension is a really important one!

If you use BasicAddonBuilder for the extension packaging (recommended)

In case you decide to provide icon(s) to execute your macros then make sure that you define all available icons (16x16 and 32x32) when prompted (even with the same icon file) because in other case you may do not find anything new in the icon bar after installation.

There are some differences between Apache OpenOffice.org 4.x and previous versions of AOO as well as with all previous and current LibreOffice versions. Thus, when creating the extension with BasicAddonBuilder, create two versions: one for AOO v.4.x. and one for AOO.up.to.3.2.and.LO and zip both into one file along with a simple readme.txt file with the simple command to install the appropriate file according to the suite installed locally.

Currently there are two repositories for Apache OpenOffice.org and LibreOffice extensions located http://extensions.openoffice.org/ and https://extensions.libreoffice.org/ respectively. Since, all macros are running naturally in both Office suites you should create an account and upload your extension in both places (or choose a third party repository like [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/) and make a link to that place)

Hope that this will help you.